# 'Merge' two objects in python

Tags: python, class, object, merge, arguments

I'm trying to figure out how to 'merge' two objects together. My goal here is to merge two `Album` objects (code below). I need to be able to merge the `tracks` argument (which are lists) of multiple `Album` objects, only if the 'title' argument of the `Album` object is the same.

Basically, if I have an `Album` object where the length of the `tracks` argument is 1 and another album object where the length of the `tracks` argument is also 1, the new, or updated singular `Album` object needs to have a `tracks` argument with a length of 2.

I've posted my code to show how the objects are defined.

Thanks in advance!

Edit : Since each element in the `tracks` argument list are names of songs, I would like to keep the same elements and put them in the new or updated `tracks` argument. Rather than just changing the amount of elements, I need to have the exact elements from each object put into this 'new' object.

```
class Album(object) :
    def __init__(self, artist, title, tracks = None) :
        tracks = []
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.tracks = tracks

    def add_track(self, track) :
        self.track = track
        (self.tracks).append(track)
        print "The track %s was added." % (track)

    def __str__(self) :
        if len(self.tracks) == 1 :
            return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + "1 Track]"
        return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + str(len(self.tracks)) + " Tracks]"
```

Comment: what you mean about `have the exact elements from each object put into this 'new' object. ` ?

Comment: @Kasra If Album object 1's `tracks` list is `['one']` and Album object 2's 'tracks' list is `['two']`, then the final `tracks` list would be `['one', 'two']`. I put this information in because I don't want just the lengths of the two lists added, I want the elements added into a new list.

Answer (score 6):

The merge algorithm has to know the internal data structure of the class.  So, it seems logical to put the merge code inside the class.  The code below does that and allows two albums to be merged simply adding them (`album1 + album2`):

```
class Album(object) :
    def __init__(self, artist, title, tracks = None) :
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.tracks = tracks

    def add_track(self, track) :
        self.track = track
        (self.tracks).append(track)
        print "The track %s was added." % (track)

    def __str__(self) :
        if len(self.tracks) == 1 :
            return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + "1 Track]"
        return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + str(len(self.tracks)) + " Tracks]"

    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.artist != other.artist or self.title != other.title:
            raise ValueError("Albums are incommensurable")
        return Album(self.artist, self.title, self.tracks + other.tracks)
```

This is used as follows:

```
>>> a = Album('Joe', "Joe's First", tracks=['Beer', 'Trucks'])
>>> b = Album('Joe', "Joe's First", tracks=['Bourbon', 'Tequila'])
>>> complete = a + b
>>> print complete
Artist: Joe, Album: Joe's First [4 Tracks]
>>> complete.tracks
['Beer', 'Trucks', 'Bourbon', 'Tequila']
```

Answer (score 0):

About keeping the same elements you don't need that you just need `if` condition to check before add tracks :

```
def add_track(self, track) :
    self.track = track
    if track not in (self.tracks) :
         (self.tracks).append(track)
    else :
         raise ValueError("duplicate track")
    print "The track %s was added." % (track)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_albums(album1, album2):
    if not album1.artist == album2.artist and \
            album1.title == album2.title:
        raise SomeException("Albums don't match")
    new_tracks = list(set(album1.tracks + album2.tracks))
    return Album(album1.artist, album1.title, new_tracks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will be merging the tracks of the albums only if artist and the title are same. One way to do this is by defining your own merge function as below:

```
class Album(object) :
    def __init__(self, artist, title, tracks = None) :
        tracks = []
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.tracks = tracks

    def add_track(self, track) :
        self.track = track
        (self.tracks).append(track)
        print "The track %s was added." % (track)

    def merge(self, album):
        if (type(self)==type(album)):
            if self.artist == album.artist and self.title==album.title:
                self.tracks.extend(album.tracks)
            else:
                print "cannot merge albums, artists or titles are not same"
        else:
            print "Invalid object types, cannot merge"
    def __str__(self) :
        if len(self.tracks) == 1 :
            return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + "1 Track]"
        return "Artist: %s, Album: %s [" % (self.artist, self.title) + \
               str(len(self.tracks)) + " Tracks]"
```

Then if you have album a, you can call a.merge(b) After merge a.tracks should contain merged tracks. You need to make other changes as desired.